# When to use Application context in Springs.

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, applicationcontext

I have to develop a full fledged project. by full fledged i mean need to insert, update delete values in a database, Performing operations on values. Its like i have set of model classes for every object. Employee, products etc. its a web application developed using Spring MVC. I know when a user enters a data in a form , the request goes to dispatcher servlet from there to a particular handler(Controller) and then to view. But i don't know what application Context or web Application Context does ? its like is it necessary to have that xml file. ? What all it contains. thanks ...

Answer (score 3):

You are right in your assumptions. What you don't know is that `DispatcherServlet` has its own context, defined in `*-servlet.xml`. This context is typically a child of a main application context, typically defined in `applicationContext.xml`. Child can access all beans defined in parent context but not the other way around.

Theoretically you can live with just a single `DispatcherServlet` context and have all beans there (DAOs, services, transaction demarcation). But this is a poor practice in a bigger projects. Also two context allow you to draw a line between business logic and web layer.

Practical implication - if you have two `DispatcherServlet`s there is no way of sharing beans between them if they don't have a common parent context.

Comment: Tomasz.. Sir , can u please provide me with a dummy code for application Context ? A basic application Context.. What i need to put in that document. Like if i have a simple class employee with 2 fields name, id.. and my project name is xyz, controllers are in the package xyz.package.. A simple jsp page form (addempl) in WebContent JSP folder. So in this regard what my application Context.xml would like be ? Or please provide me with a link Thanks.

Comment: @user1230183: no code sample, sorry. But you will find **plethora** of code samples and tutorials in the net. Just google "*spring mvc tutorial*". Also you might [this](https://github.com/nurkiewicz/books) sample project I created some time ago useful.

Comment: You should definitely try out spring-roo. With it you can setup the whole project structure with all applicationContext files you need in a matter of seconds.